# How to convert Index as column variable in R (Data downloaded from Yahoo finance)

Tags: r, yahoo-finance

I want the index column as date for my data but it is showing as index when I downloaded the data from yahoo finance.

[image]

I tried using rownames() function, but didn't get the result

Comment: You can use `zoo::fortify.zoo(yourdata)`

Comment: Or try `rownames_to_colum("my_date")` after downloading.

Comment: `x$date <- rownames(x)` (base), `x <- tibble::rownames_to_column(x)` (tidyverse), and akrun's `zoo::fortify.zoo(.)` are all ways to do this.

Comment: (after those steps, you may need to convert to a proper `Date` object using `x$date <- as.Date(x$date)`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are using `quantmod::getSymbols` to download the data then the data is an xts/zoo time series object so there are no row names on the data and the date is already in Date format.  Only akrun's comment and answer actually work in that case.   You may wish to consider not converting it in the first place.  You likely don't need to have a data frame at all. Having it as a time series object may be more convenient.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you're correct.
is there a way to download data from yahoo finance with Date as column and not as Index?

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(zoo)
fortify.zoo(HCLTECH)
```

Comment: Thank you 
fortify.zoo(HCLTECH) - Worked